# Arc Length and Differential Forms

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Suppose $\gamma$ is circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by coordinates $\begin{pmatrix}r\cos\theta\\r\sin\theta\\0\end{pmatrix}$, and function $F: \gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is defined by $F(\gamma(\theta)) = \begin{pmatrix}-\sin\theta \\ \cos\theta\\0\end{pmatrix}$, and let 1-form in $\mathbb{R}^3$$\lambda_F = F_1dx+F_2dy+F_3dz$, where $F_i$ is the component of $F$.

Why $\int_\gamma{\lambda_F}$ is the length of the circle $\gamma$?

I know that one can do some calculation like $\int_\gamma{\lambda_F} = \int_0^{2\pi}\vert\gamma'(\theta)\vert d\theta = 2\pi r$, what I'm asking is an intuitive explanation, i.e. why when you put that specific $\lambda_F$ there, it gives you the arclength, intuitively.

Thanks.

Comment: Your 1-form works *because* is handpicked to achieve a integral = arclength. Can you generalize the idea to *any* parametrized curve?

Comment: Just remind you that $\lambda_F$ is NOT a one form on $\mathbb R^3$. It's a one form long $\gamma$ only.

Comment: BTW, your definition works because you can use $\theta$. What is the definition of $F(\text{point of $\gamma$})$ *without* using $\theta$?

Comment: @John Thanks, didn't notice that.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Yes, I choose that $F$ on purpose, because what I am wondering is the meaning of this $F$. It's on the book "Principles of Mathematical Analysis", page 286 (2en ed).

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I don't think it has any thing to do with "the $\theta$ thing". It's just a definition of $F$, you can define it any way you want, as long as when applied at point $\gamma(\theta)$, it yields that specific vector.

Comment: 10.48 Integrals of...? Is the general definition of line integral. And your definition of $F$ "cheats" because passing from point of the curve to value of parameter, while in theory is simply taking the inverse, in the practice can be very hard or impossible for an arbitrary curve.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Yes, section 10.48. Yes, it could be hard for arbitrary curves, but as long as the curve is parametrized and differentiable, you can define $F(\gamma(\theta))$ to be $\vert \gamma'(\theta) \vert (\gamma'_1(\theta), \gamma'_2(\theta), \gamma'_3(\theta))^T$. Yeah... it's definition relies on the parameter $\theta$.

Comment: Going back to my first comment... You can handpick the differential form and obtain the arclenght.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\gamma:[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb R^3$ be a parametrized curve. Near a point $(t_0, \gamma(t_0))$,
$$\gamma(t)\approx \gamma'(t_0)(t-t_0)+\gamma(t_0)$$
i.e.
$$\|\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_0)\|\approx\|\gamma'(t_0)\||t-t_0|$$
or,
$$\Delta(\text{length})\approx\|\gamma'(t)\|\Delta t.$$
What happens in the limit?

Answer (score 0):

Use Pythagoras.

The arc length between the points $A$ and $B$ is approximated by the length of the straight segment $AB$. If $A=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $B=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ then $AB=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}$.

When $A$ and $B$ are close together then $x_2-x_1\sim (F\circ\gamma_1)'d\theta=F_1d\theta$. Similarly for $y_2-y_1$ and $z_2-z_1$.

Answer (score 0):

set $\phi_x=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}, \phi_y=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}, dx=\phi_xdt, dy=\phi_ydt$

as $\frac{\phi_x}{\sqrt{\phi_x^2+\phi_y^2}}dx+\frac{\phi_y}{\sqrt{\phi_x^2+\phi_y^2}}dy=\sqrt{\phi_x^2+\phi_y^2}dt$

and this is the definition of the arc-length. From this, you can know the answer of your question since $cos(\theta),sin(\theta)$are in fact the $\phi$ here.

Comment: If $\phi=\cos\theta$ what is $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\,?$ Remark about  OP: it strikes me that nobody mentioned in almost 10 years that OP's vector field is tangent to the circle (of any radius) and has speed one. Therefore its line integral is the arc length.